# Mapbox warning setAccessToken requires setWellKnownTileServer for MapLibre Blank Screen - React Native expo

Tags: react-native, expo, mapbox, maplibre-gl

**App.js**

```js
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import MapboxGL from '@rnmapbox/maps';
MapboxGL.setAccessToken('TOKEN');
export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.page}>
          <MapboxGL.MapView style={styles.map} />
          <StatusBar style="auto"/>
      </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  page: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF'
  },
  map: {
    flex: 1
  }
});
```

**Giving this error :**
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9140v.png)

> Mapbox warning setAccessToken requires setWellKnownTileServer for MapLibre, see setWellKnownTileServer docs for implications Object {
> "level": "warning",
> "message": "setAccessToken requires setWellKnownTileServer for MapLibre, see setWellKnownTileServer docs for implications",
> "tag": "InstanceManagerImpl",

**And blank screen:**
[blank react native screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j36At.png)

Answer (score 2):

Your map has nothing to show. Add *styleJSON* or *styleURL* option. For example (osm tiles):

```js
const defaultStyle = {
  version: 8,
  name: 'Land',
  sources: {
    map: {
      type: 'raster',
      tiles: ['https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'],
      tileSize: 256,
      minzoom: 1,
      maxzoom: 19,
    },
  },
  layers: [
    {
      id: 'background',
      type: 'background',
      paint: {
        'background-color': '#f2efea',
      },
    },
    {
      id: 'map',
      type: 'raster',
      source: 'map',
      paint: {
        'raster-fade-duration': 100,
      },
    },
  ],
};

// -- map component
<MapboxGL.MapView
  style={styles.map}
  styleJSON={JSON.stringify(defaultStyle)}
/>
```

Comment: ERROR  TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'MapboxGL.StyleURL')

Comment: Native part of Mapbox React Native libraries were not registered properly, double check our native installation guides.

Comment: After adding styles

Comment: @SRJOY are you using expo go or built dev-client?

Comment: I'm using expo , Also tried built dev-client , none of them worked!

Comment: EAS build works!

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by adding one line to my code:

MapboxGL.setWellKnownTileServer('Mapbox');

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).